# Choosing between the two - Interface Builder OR creating via code

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

When I started with IPhone development I preferred using **Interface builder** for creating views in my application. With time I considered the option of creating the application **via code** which I really feel comfortable working with.
Now, when I know both ways to create my user interface, I have doubts which way to follow. I keep thinking where to use **IB** and where to use **code**. How can I figure out before starting with my application, which way should I create my **UI**?

Comment: Exactly how I feel... doing most things in code now and start to revert back to IB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are a number of factors that can influence your choice. It can come down to personal taste, but there are some advantages to using Interface Builder.

The first thing to recognize is that **UI design is inherently a visual task**. Interface Builder can allow you to create and modify a UI much faster than you can in code. Rather than endlessly tweaking CGRect values in code, then recompiling, testing, and repeating this process, you can instead get direct visual feedback about your changes. This means you can refine and polish the UI much more efficiently, and even test out radically different layouts without too much time or effort.

Another important point is that if you can create and layout a control in Interface Builder, that means there is **less code** in your view controller. Less code is always a good thing (less bugs, easier to maintain, ...).

So I believe you should try to define as much of the layout and properties in Interface Builder as you can. This can be hard for people who prefer "full control" over things. Many years ago, visual GUI editors were renowned for doing the wrong thing, and developers often shunned their use over doing everything by hand. But Interface Builder is pretty good at what it does, and you can easily dive into code when you need to.

The situations where you would create controls purely in code are when you need to dynamically create a number of objects, for example thumbnail buttons for a photo gallery, or if you have custom layout requirements.

For example, if you have a label whose height is dynamic at runtime, and you want to layout a bunch of controls underneath it (taking its height into consideration), that can only be done in code (**UPDATE:** iOS 6's Auto-layout can do this now). You can either create and layout *everything* in code, or you can still create the controls using Interface Builder and just give them arbitrary positions in the XIB which are modified when you lay them out in code. It's not uncommon to see this in some of my XIBs:

[image]

The buttons along the top can be created and layed out fully in IB, but the image views below need their images and positions to be calculated at runtime. So we just give them arbitrary positions in the XIB. Some might find this ugly, but it saves time and effort on writing code to create the image views and set up their properties. Again, less code is a good thing.

Other times you may want to use code is setting certain explicit properties. Let's say you have an image view which needs to receive touch events because it has some gesture recognizers added to it. You need to set the "User Interaction Enabled" property to TRUE. It can be better to do this in code because the requirement is more visible and you can leave appropriate comments as to why you are setting the property. It's also harder to 'lose' the setting like you can in interface builder if you need to delete and recreate a bunch of views.

Comment: Great answer Mike. I know that both IB and code can be reused to create other views. And both need to be changed somehow. In such a situation where you have similar views, which approach you suggest I should consider?

Comment: Generally, I agree with your assessment. Static layouts do benefit from efficiency increases of visual layout. It's not less code, however. It's just taken that code and dumped it into a giant XML file, in a format that has no DTD or schema. If Apple should change IB radically and not support your project's XIB format, you're in a bind. Yes, highly theoretical perhaps, but anyone valuing their project's vitality should view closed formats with some skepticism.

Answer (score 2):

I think for many applications that use the stock UI, Interface Builder is a great tool to rapidly get things up and linked with the underlying code.  Also, it really stresses the paradigm of the View being separated from the Controller as you really can't push code into places where it shouldn't be.

That being said, I use it less and less the more I learn about how to rapidly code interfaces due to the fact that they may need to be more flexible or need a variable number of UI elements based on the Model behind it.

Answer (score 1):

Use interface builder as per your requirement. It's depend on you that how you manage things. See creating a custom cell using interface builder is much easier to update at a later stage while using code you have to do a lot of changes if layout changes. Also you can visualize the view before running the actual app but in code you cannot you just have to assume.There are both prons and cons of both things.

Comment: If the code I use to create my UI is usable, should I go for code? Because at the same time IB can be reused.

Comment: I've pretty much stopped using IB for table cells (and tend to avoid it except for mostly static screens, like a login or about screen). It may make some things easier, but if (for example) you have lots of similar cells with slightly different heights/layout for different types of content, you want to do dynamic layout based on the number of lines of text, and sometimes the customer asks you to change font sizes/cell heights, doing layout in code is worth the effort.