# When using object-oriented programming in as3, is it okay to put some code on the timeline?

Tags: actionscript-3, object

I am just getting into object oriented programming, and I was wondering, is it okay to put some code on the timeline, like stop(); and mouseclick events for moving frames, or should all this be on separate files also? If they do belong in other files, how would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MPO is that you should learn the tool as the tool. I think that the timeline is the very best part of Flash, and if you throw that away, you are making your life harder for no good reason. I think *all* tools have a "code way" and "some other" way to accomplish what they do, and the default of most developers is to assume that the code way demonstrates your skillz and that "the other way" is so obviously easy that it's not worth your time to learn it.

IME, nothing could be further from the truth. I have learned these "other ways" in several tools/language, and you pretty much always get more power and productivity out of knowing both, at the risk of having a significant fraction of your fellow developers looking down their noses at you because they assume that if you're really good at "the other way" that you are doing it because you can't code. For this reason, there are very few developers who truly understand the full depth and subtlety of the timeline, and there are almost none who [will talk](http://www.meetup.com/atlflex/files) about [how to do this well](http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html).

I actually develop scalable enterprise-level Flash applications *using the timeline* for clients whose stores you've almost certainly been in within the past couple of days, so I do have a fair amount of experience in this area. My rule of thumb is that stop() is ok if it is unimportant to the overall functioning of the program (it's a visual thing only). However, it gets tedious after a while to keep adding it, so when you get to where you're not under deadline pressure, you'll probably replace that at some point with a Class that uses [addFrameScript](http://troyworks.com/blog/2007/09/22/as3-movieclipaddframescript/) to do the stop().

The best use for timeline code is when you need to synchronize things (for example, with a streaming sound, which has absolutely zero Actionscript handles to get hold of it). Generate a bubbling event at the precise point where the narrator is saying "click the thingamajig" and you've animated the cursor over the thingamajig. Then, in the AS code that controls the parent of the timeline with the streaming sound (or grandparent, or whatever--somewhere positioned to catch the event), you'd put the thingamjig into the toggled state (for example by changing the data model the thingamajig is responsible for displaying).

Very, very occasionally, I will use timeline code to do something more significant. One example is that a swf compiled by Flash Builder knows what color its stage is, but one compiled by Flash Pro does not, without [reading the bytes of the swf](http://blog.natebeck.net/2010/12/tip-of-the-day-getting-a-swfs-background-color/). I have a Class that fades a graphic in that can only get the real stage color sometimes, depending on how it was compiled (I'm not goint through the mess of reading the bytes--that's frankly ridiculous). So, I just assume we're fading in from white or something close to it (which we are most of the time). For the rare case where it's not, I've noted in the ASDOCs for the Class that it's ok to just populate the color variable from the timeline rather than worry about how to get it in there through dependency injection. I view this as kind of a poor man's version of the [Flash Components](http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/943/4/Actionscript-and-timelines/Page4.html) properties panel.

Hope that points you in the right direction :).

Comment: Wow, great advice, and great links. Thank you, I thought all the stops and mouseclicks might get tedious, ad never thought about using a class file this way!

Comment: I think it's important to treat code on the timeline purely as if you're building a rich animation as a resource. `MovieClip` related code like `stop()` and so on is obviously vital, but (for example), adding new instances in an animation is an easy way to accidentally create memory leaks. I don't think the aversion of developers is some arrogant thing, it's the fact that it's hard to understand what is and isn't a good idea on the timeline until you have more experience with its quirks.

Comment: It's no easier or harder to create memory leaks using the stage/timeline than creating everything through code. You absolutely have to understand what you're doing using _any_ technique. The reason this workflow is so poorly understood by the majority of developers is that Macromedia/Adobe made the decision early on to point developers to a "code only" model, rather than teaching them how to combine the timeline and code to the full potential of the too.

Comment: It is good to find some confirmation on this practice. As the Lead Developer at my company, I've made it our standard to keep pure code (of which there is a lot) in the classes of our game core, and interface-related code on the timeline of the object it is directly modifying. Saves a lot of time, because we don't have to chase down an obscure class file to find our event listeners. I've taken a lot of flak for this approach, but we've saved a LOT of time this way. (And, by creating visual elements WYSIWYG, we avoid ticking off our animators.)

Comment: Glad it helps. If I thought Flash had a vibrant future, I'd write a book about this technique. I felt in my gut there had to be people out there doing this stuff, but no one talks about it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what you mean by is it okay. (no I am not Bill Clinton)

You'll be hard pressed to get a positive response on this as most of the community on SO are developers and generally are not huge fans of using the Flash IDE/Timeline coding.

That being said, I try to always remain open minded and do realize there's a place for the Flash IDE in creating motion graphics quickly, etc.  There's nothing that says you should not code in the timeline, if you absolutely shouldn't do it, they wouldn't have made it possible.

The problem I think arises when you start working with other developers and have to figure out where they buried some code on the timeline within some movieclip that is affecting things.  For small projects this isn't really an issue, getting into larger teams (3-5 devs at a time, maybe more) then being able to work independently and collaboratively becomes a challenge.

One last point since you say you're just learning OOP.  AS3 is a great language, tons of fun, lots of features provided by the run-time so you can just jump past some of the nitty gritty in C/C++ etc.  But the concept of the Timeline is unique to AS3.  So if you learn to do everything based on the Timeline, then moving to say C++ or Java or C# or any other OOP will likely be that much more difficult.  For now I wouldn't stress about this since you're just getting rolling, but just something to keep in your mind as you move forward.

**Edit (response to Ms. Blankenship's good answer and comments from Mr. Mear)**

I think there is some arrogance on the side of developers.  I can speak for myself in saying I've generally not been a fan of WYSIWYG editors (except when I try to build them, then they're okay :).

A couple of reasons:

1. They have in my past experience been terrible (take Word or DreamWeaver's code output as examples, try to work on a site some mom and pop threw together in one of those apps and you'll start to hate it too).
2. If someone was able to get this completely right it would invalidate a lot of knowledge I've built up (so it gets me into a defensive stance, not an objectively valid reason, I know).
3. Working with bigger teams finding code is key + the code editor is bad (compared with any of the alternatives, Flash Builder [my tool of choice], FDT, FlashDevelop, IntelliJ [my friends' tool of choice]).
4. Coming from a OOP background that doesn't include anything similar to the Timeline and potentially moving back to those technologies.  You have the choice to be great at 1 thing or good at 5 things what do you choose? (I'm vastly over simplifying but hopefully you get the gist).  I learned to use Eclipse writing Java, I can use the same tool to write C++, C, PHP, etc.  This isn't to say I actually always use Eclipse for everything (lately been using SublimeText a fair amount), but I like that it's always an option.  As an aside I'm not an Eclipse "Pure Blood", I started off early on playing with Flash IDE and HTML/JS in Notepad, used Visual Studio for a bit, eventually got pushed into Eclipse but have taken a liking to it for the all in oneness.

Ultimately there are too many factors in this open ended situation to say that one solution is the end all be all.  To explain with an analogy, if you were to build a birdhouse a hammer, some nails, and some wood are probably all you need.  If instead you want to build your own human house you're going to need some different tools (probably including a hammer, some nails and wood).

Also a related SO post (re-hashes many of the same points):
[Why not use Interface Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773571/why-not-use-interface-builder)

Comment: Yeah, it's just a small 1 man project, but I just wanted to make sure working in the timeline as well as with my external .as files wouldn't produce any errors, thank you!

Comment: It really does depend. I think the code-only approach displays a certain myopia when the programmer is working with any non-programmers, which is somewhat common in team projects. Yet, solo projects sometimes work better code-only. Just one more reason why I detest the misnomer "best practice," which implies there is only one good way to do it. (I prefer "good practice", which better reflects that relativity.)

Comment: MPO is that you should have a really solid understanding of the _reason_ behind the best practice, then decide if it really is best practice. For example, the "best practice" of not using anonymous functions became best practice when understanding of the more functional aspects of AS wasn't yet solidified. So for a newbie, an anonymous function is absolutely bad practice. But in some situations, they can _limit_ the scope available to e.g. an event handler and _prevent_ instead of cause memory leaks. The problem is, to make these calls you have to be confident and actually know your stuff.